# FontSlant plain mode not working

Tags: plotting

Whenever I have subscripts in my labels, the FontSlant seems to change to italic. I want the plain style, even for legends.
How to fix it?

```
Plot[x^3 + 1, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(a\)]\)(m^3)", 
   "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(a\)]\)/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \
\(b\)]\)"}, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
   FontSlant -> "Plain"], 
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 14, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSlant -> "Plain"], 
 PlotRange -> {-30, 300}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(abc\)]\)"}, {Scaled[{0.95, 
      0.15}], {0.95, 0.35}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: You really should use Latex for all your labels. It looks much better than anything Mathematica has. Check MaTeX package.

Comment: @nasser  Thanks very much, I'll check that.

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[x^3 + 1, {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> ({"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(a\)]\)" // 
      StandardForm // DisplayForm, 
    "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(a\)]\)/\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(Y\), \(b\
\)]\)" // StandardForm // DisplayForm}), FrameStyle -> Black, 
 LabelStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica", 
   FontSlant -> "Plain"], 
 FrameStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontColor -> Black, FontSize -> 14, 
   FontFamily -> "Helvetica", FontSlant -> "Plain"], 
 PlotRange -> {-30, 300}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[{"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(T\), \(abc\)]\)" // StandardForm // 
     DisplayForm}, {Scaled[{0.95, 0.15}], {0.95, 0.35}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: There is a problem here now that the FontFamily does not work anymore!@Syed

Comment: Perhaps someone will add a `MateX` solution to this page. This was a convenient hack and obviously has its limits.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it helped though